# Can I use ReCaptcha in a public script? (in regards to API keys)

Tags: recaptcha

I'm writing a PHP script, and want to include ReCaptcha

However, is it safe to use my private/public API keys in the script? I mean I could enable it for all domains, or would users just have to register with Google and get a key?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe. Yoy have to register and write your domain or you can create global key for all domains but it will work with your private key.